# Is it possible to import Tridion CM DB into Azure by BACPAC file?

Tags: azure, cm-db

I'll upgrade exisiting Tridion 2013 SP1 to SDL Web 8.5.
Also I'll move DBs and CMS to Microsoft Azure.

To move Tridion CM DB to Azure SQL Database, I tried to create BACPAC file of the DB, but it failed with several errors.

Error messages are something like,

> Dependent object '[C].[value] (UnresolvedEntity)'  does not exists in
> this database.
>
> Dependent object '[dbo].[EDA_ITEM_ASSOCIATIONS_CREATE] (StoredProcedure)' is not
> supported.

Is it possible to move Tridion CM DB into Azure SQL Database by using BACPAC file?

If anyone have experience of migrating Tridion to Azure, please tell me how to move Tridion CM DB to Azure SQL Database.

It seems that Data Migration Assistant can import Tridion CM DB into Azure SQL Database , but BACPAC looks more handy.

Following image show error messages(Japanese).

[image]